# Jquery that containn multiple checkbox using lightbox

Tags: jquery

Can any one help me to create a pop up that contain multiple check box and after selecting option that values come in text box and if we want to remove particular selection then it allows us from textbox.

In short I want to do like this:

1. Go to [this page](http://in.iproperty.com/).
2. Check `Please click here to select sub location(s)`

Comment: Actully I am getting value,but if you have seen that text box allows remove option for selected item.

Comment: Check the function named `fnCloseSubLocationBox` in the script files.

Comment: Can you give me link from where I can see this type of examples ?